# Using PHPStorm against the Drupal code base produces many false errors

Tags: php, drupal, phpstorm

Has anyone managed to use PHPStorm with the Drupal code base? I keep getting many false errors about undefined variables. I've added *.module, *.inc, etc to the list of PHP file types but I still get errors.

Comment: I haven't played with PHPStorm since the beta, but on a hunch: most IDEs won't analyse the code of included files etc unless they're opened as a proper project. Are you perhaps opening a single .php, like index.php?

Comment: Nope. I've included the whole Drupal folder in the project :(

Comment: Can you give a more specific example of the false errors that you are getting?  Maybe list one of the undefined variables error you are seeing?

Comment: Sure Mike, if I open up install.php, I keep getting errors on things like $profile->filename, $profile->name, @translations, $locale->name, etc.

Comment: When do you get these errors?  Are you getting them when you try to debug?

Comment: Nope. When I just open the file. It's the errors/warnings that the code inspection reports.

Comment: No PHPStorm experience here, but from yor examples, it looks as if it might not like Drupals common usage of stdClass objects with on the fly properties. I'd dig through the settings options and look for a way to configure the error/warning levels.

Answer (score 1):

To get a rid most of the false errors, turn off the "Undefined field" and "Undefined method" (only in case of Drupal 7) inspections. You can locate them in Settings -> IDE Settings -> Inspections -> PHP.

Also, don't forget to add .module, .install, .inc, .test extensions as PHP files.